# Filter by version SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, select

I have the following table:
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYoQh.png)

I would like to filter by max(version) for each "UFI" and "PERIODO_QH".

I have tried to use max(VERSION) but I have to group for ALL the rest of the columns so I obtain many versions due to the fact that the rest of the columns changes its values.

What I need in this example, it is to obtain only 2 rows, one for each UFI:

```
UFI  
===============================
ALZ1 NUCLEAR 90 200 68,72 68
ALZ2 NUCLEAR 35 100 68,72 39
```

What query should I do? Maybe I should not use MAX() an group by expression?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question could do with some improvement: please add data as text not as a picture. Please use the correct tag for the database (Oracle maybe?). The general approach is to first work out only the correct `UFI, PERIODO_QH, VERSION` (can you write a query that returns only that?) then you just join it back to the original table to get all required columns.

Comment: Also can you throw a different value for `PERIODO_QH` in your sample input data so we know how that's meant to operate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select *
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over(partition by ufi, tecnologia order by version desc) as rn
  from t
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: It should work in Oracle 12.1 or newer. What version do you have?

Comment: It has worked, thank you so much!